# Substring values into multiple textboxes

Tags: c#

I want to seperate multiple values from a gridview control and show it in four textboxes. Is that possible?
Right now I get this value: [image]

With this code:

```
        var lblRef = new Label
                         {
                             Text = ((Label) row.FindControl("LabelAssignmentReference")).Text
                         };

        string valueTextBox = lblRef.Text;
        int indexOfRefSwe = valueTextBox.IndexOf(",", StringComparison.Ordinal);
        string valueRef = valueTextBox.Substring(0, indexOfRefSwe);

        TextBoxReference.Text = valueRef;
```

But how do i get it in multiple values? `            TextBoxReference.Text = valueRef;

```
        TextBoxRefPhone.Text = "??";
        TextBoxRefEmail.Text = "??";
        TextBoxRefDesc.Text = "??";`
```

Comment: `lblRef.Split(new [] { ',' });` will return an array of the values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you started.

```
string[] splits = lblRef.Text.Split(',');
Console.WriteLine(splits[0]); // refname
Console.WriteLine(splits[1]); // 08712332
Console.WriteLine(splits[2]); // ref@gmail.com
Console.WriteLine(splits[3]); // refdescription
```

I suggest also adding validation checks to make sure you don't get any errors, such as checking that `splits.Length == 4` as expected.

Note that the spaces will be included in the beginning of the last three elements of `splits`. You can eliminate those using the `Trim` method, or by providing an array of delimiters `new[] {',', ' '}` to the `split` function and ignore empty elements (there's an overload for that).

Comment: I've tried this one but filled in my textboxes instead of console.writeline. .Trim() afterwards. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

There is `System.String.Split()`-method:

```
string[] parts = str.Split(new char[] {','});
```

Afterwards, work on the parts.

Example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
using System;

public class SplitTest {
    public static void Main() {

        string words = "This is a list of words, with: a bit of punctuation" +
                       "\tand a tab character.";

        string [] split = words.Split(new Char [] {' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' });

        foreach (string s in split) {

            if (s.Trim() != "")
                Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do as below

```
var values = lblRef.Text.Split(',');

TextBoxRefPhone.Text = values[0];
if(values.Length>0)
   TextBoxRefEmail.Text =values[1];
if(values.Length>1)
  TextBoxRefDesc.Text = values[2];
```

**Edit**

there is a Split overload method which accept `params`. so we can give one character

```
public string[] Split(params char[] separator);
```

> The **params** keyword lets you specify a method parameter that takes an
>   argument where **the number of arguments is variable**.

Comment: Split requires an array of values.

Comment: @stuartd Wrong. You can provide a single delimiter without an array. The method has many overloads.

Comment: To clarify, split will accept a single char value, but if you want to use a string, then it has be passed in an array.

Comment: @stuartd params for that. I think you learn few things today :)